# redirect .htaccess from folder to domain with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect only  a folder with parameter to a new domain, for example:

from

```
www.domain.it/en/page/2/products
```

to

```
www.domain.com/page/2/products
```

How I do it?

I tried this but is not working for my pourpose:

```
RewriteCond $1 !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/en/ -d
RewriteRule (.+) http://www.domain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following mod-alias based solution

```
Redirect /en/ http://domain.com/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... is not a good way. This solution generate a duplicate page:

from
www.domain.it/en/page/2/products

to
http://www.domain.com/products/2/products?id=2&name=chairs

when the origianle page should be
http://www.domain.com/products/2/products

Comment: @Luca Does your old url also contain the query string? sorry for the late reply.